# Filter pymongo query based on timedelta for two fields for each document

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using MongoDB and Python to work with a collection where each document looks like this:

```
{_id: 'e82d0b5c-5e38-4442-a678-f29245681238',
start_time: '2020-02-25T20:45:10.623Z',
stop_time: '2020-02-26T21:45:10.623Z',
data: {cost: 3, buyer: 'John'}}
```

I would like to find all documents in my collection for which the difference between start_time and stop_time is superior to 24 hours. One potential issue I considered is that the format for start_time and stop_time is String, and not Date, but I am able to generate a cursor using:

```
db['collection'].find({'stop_time':{'$gte': 'start_time'}})
```

But I cannot generate a cursor using any of the following:

```
db['collection'].find({'stop_time':{'$gte': 'start_time' + datetime.timedelta(hours=24)}})
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "datetime.timedelta") to str
```

```
db['collection'].find({'stop_time':{'$gte': {'$toDate': 'start_time'} + datetime.timedelta(hours=24)}})
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

I apologize if this is found to be a duplicate, but I haven't managed to find a post solving my problem. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: You can use the aggregate operator `$dateDiff`  or `$subtract`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with an aggregate

```
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "date_diff": {
        "$subtract": [
          {
            "$dateFromString": {
              "dateString": "$stop_time"
            }
          },
          {
            "$dateFromString": {
              "dateString": "$start_time"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "date_diff": {
        "$gte": 86400000 //24*3600*1000
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I first use `$addFields`, to create a new field that will contain the difference between the two dates.
To calculate that difference I use `$subtract`, but before I convert the string to a date format with `$dateFromString`

Then we can filter only the documents that have a difference greater or equal to 24 hours (or 86400000 milliseconds) with a `$match`.

try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TjYrJuLrf89)